# Not getting proper indentation in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, string-formatting

I have a stored procedure which returns a table which i take into a list and set it to Datagridview. The table returned by the stored Procedure is like this:

[image]

---

**And the datagridview is like this:**

[image]

---

The problem is that i want the indentation of the first column as it is in the DataGridView. The datagridview trims the starting Spaces of the Name field(First Column).

Comment: I don't think the `DataGridView` trims the spaces, it may be because of your code. So show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a CTE, I used '----' instead of 'spaces'. I had the same problem. Below is my question and the demo answered by Romesh.

[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631194/tree-view-using-sql-query/18633766#18633766)

[Demo by Romesh](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ff31/23)

Sure it looks a bit untidy but it gets the job done.

OR

Have a look at this

[GridView is trimming leading spaces. Can I stop that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517434/gridview-is-trimming-leading-spaces-can-i-stop-that)

Comment: Thanxx for the reply.....Though i was using stored procedure with different queries, i think i should use cte now for my stored procedure.